# Async/Await with Microsoft Unity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, unity-container

I have a project that uses Microsoft Unity and Web API 2. It works great and there are no problems with it. However when I try to use async/await

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(PackageOrderDto dto)
{
    try
    {
        newOrderNumber = await _apiPlaceOrder.Save(dto));
    }
    catch (ApiValidationFailedException apiValidationFailedException)
    {
        return BadRequest(apiValidationFailedException);
    }
    return Ok("VF" + newOrderNumber);
}
```

I get a ResolutionFailedException with this message:

Exception is:

> InvalidOperationException - The PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be
>   used in the context of an HTTP request. Possible causes for this error
>   are using the lifetime manager on a non-ASP.NET application, or using
>   it in a thread that is not associated with the appropriate
>   synchronization context.

The `ApiPlaceOrder` is managed using UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver.

The code works fine when async/await is not used.

Any ideas how to get Unity to play nice with async/await?

I've stripped the code for `_apiPlaceOrder.Save(...)` right back to this to try and isolate the problem and I still get the same issue:

```
public class ApiPlaceOrder
{
    public async Task<int> Save(PackageOrderDto dto)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `_apiPlaceOrder.Save` implemented? Also where does the exception gets thrown? Post the stack trace too

Comment: Please try using the Nuget package Unitiy.WebAPI and the HierarchicalLifetimeManager and UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver instead of your current setup. If that works, I can give you an explanation.

Comment: @JotaBe I'm already doing both of those things. They are necessary to work with WebAPI

Comment: Your error clearly states that you are using "PerRequestLifetimeManager", not "HierarchicalLifetimeManager". I can't guess if you're using "UnityHierarchicalDependencyResolver" or not.

Comment: Actually it stated "per-request", but you're right that is confusing. I've changed the post.

Comment: Does it work if you configure the awaiter to continue on the current thread? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you mean run it synchronously? It works fine if I do that.

Comment: Are you trying to use a single EntityFramework context across threads?

Comment: @Stephen nope, not even using EF.

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error when you are using `PerRequestLifetimeManager` in the Unity.Mvc project and `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.  That will occur when you are no longer on the originating thread of the http request.

Check your code for any occurrences of `await fooTask.ConfigureAwait(false)` or something that is creating a new thread or acquiring a thread from the thread pool.  Hook up a debugger and put `HttpContext.Current` in your watch window and step through your code until that property switches to `null`.